# laravel package development and link to css/js file

Tags: laravel, package-development

I am new in laravel package development and i want to link to css and js files in main view.

I do this, but it links to project path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path('css/style.css') }}">
```

but i want to link to css/js files in package directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should publish the assets on the vendor first by running

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

But, to do that, you also need to set the config on the package service provider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/public' => public_path('vendor/bryanjack/dash'),
    ]);
}
```

And then your package will be published on the public directory

Answer (score 0):

`asset()` method is used to include CSS/JavaScript/images files, you can use it in your case
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"/>
```